How to create LetsEncrypt certificate for AWS EC2 single instance on Linux 2023?
I would like to install a Lets Encrypt certificate on Amazon EC2 single instance running .NET Core on Linux 2023. I am using the instructions below, however I am not sure where to create the certificate and obtain the private key? Can I do that on my local machine? Or do I need to first deploy my code without the ebextensions, ssh to the server and create the certificate, then redeploy the code with the ebextension?
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/https-singleinstance-dotnet-linux.html

You can refer to this video that I created Deploying .NET API on Amazon Linux EC2 | Custom Domain | SSL certificate with Let's Encrypt. This link will directly take you to the SSL integration part. Hope it helps.
